# Powerbi ability to create snapshot data from a historical table of data

Tags: powerbi, measure

I have a sql database linked where I have the complete history of products and users. I want to the user to be able to select on the slicer a year and the data automatically shows active prodcuts, expired products and new products added in that year (or snapshot).

Is there a way this can be done? I am not able to find a measure to best do this for me.

Comment: Read this: [Get started with Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a date dimension table first - I usually call mine Calendar. Please read this useful post by Radacad which will show you how to create one > https://radacad.com/power-bi-date-or-calendar-table-best-method-dax-or-power-query

Once it's done create relationships between your fact tables and calendar table on key dates of when your products are active or expired - I'm making a huge assumption that's what your tables store.
Your calendar table will then act as a single time/date point of truth and should be used to slice and dice your fact table.
Hope this helps!